# How to copy files on remote Windows to local Linux on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, scp

Currently, I'm working on a local Linux machine. I'm trying to use scp or similar Linux command-line tools to copy files from a remote Windows machine to my local Linux. I did some searching and found that most of the solutions are for local Windows cases (like putty and winscp), which don't really help.

Please advise.Thank you.

[UPDATE] Solved by installing cygwin's sshd service on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use SCP, you will need an SCP server (actually an SSH server) on the Windows machine.

For example [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/).

You will need to choose one of the options based on your own needs, there are a number of similar tools and freeSSHd was the first in the list on Google. I've used the [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) in the past but it is only free for non-commercial use.

They are usually very easy to set up. You install them the usual way and run them for the first time. Depending on the tool, they may pick up your existing Windows users or you may need to manually create some users with passwords within the tool. Then, armed with your PC's IP address, you should be able to connect to the PC using SSH from the Linux command line.

Comment: That seems to be what I want...Can you please share more information on how to use a SCP server on windows? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have decided to use cygwin's sshd and it really works. Just to mention that on Windows you probably need to turn off the firewall in order to accept incoming ssh connection.

Comment: OK, forgot Cygwin - that works too though a bit harder to config maybe. Please don't turn off the firewall though as that is rather (very) dangerous. The advantage to the Windows tools is that they should configure the firewall for you. Otherwise, edit the firewall settings and allow port 22 inbound.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for copying from remote Windows 10 machine with [built-in SSH server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse). Note forward slashes and drive style. Domain is not necessary.

```
scp user@domain@example.com:c:/path/to/file.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

If the windows system has a shared folder you should be able access that with smbclient which is part of the terrific samba project.

Usually somthing like:

```
smbclient //winmachine/share
```

Possibly using the `-U username` options to specifiy the username on the windows box.

Once connected, you can use `cd` to change folders, and `get` to retrieve files.

If there is no file share.... I dunno. Create one?